# How could one let the Manipulation or GestureListener work in the page which contains a WebBrowser in it?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

My application page contains a `WebBrowser`. I want to add a `GestureListener` in order to handle the Flick event. But when Flick on the `WebBrowser` region, it doesn't work. I have tried many ways to let it work, but I failed. I have also tried to use Manipulation instead, but to no effect.

Could someone tell me how to do or whether there is another solution instead?

Answer (score 1):

Following code is the working solution for the Flick or Hold event on the `WebBrowser` control.
Try the same, it may help you.

Assuming `xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"` being present in the `phone:PhoneApplicationPage` tag.

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="myWebBrowser" Visibility="Visible" IsScriptEnabled="True" IsHitTestVisible="True" Margin="-12,6,0,6" />
            <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="GestureListener_Flick" Hold="GestureListener_Hold"></toolkit:GestureListener>
            </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        </Grid>
```

And xaml.cs has functions as follows.

```
private void GestureListener_Flick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Flick");
        }

        private void GestureListener_Hold(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hold");
        }
```

Comment: The above solution will work but note you will not be able to gain any contextual information from within the webbrowser control to use for your gestures.  You also cannot interact with the webbrowser control wither, it is very much just a HTML viewer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply！ If I set the WebBrowser's IsHitTestVisible property to false, the GestureListener works. But I also need to interact with the WebBrowser.